# Preserve volume Vertex group

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, bones, surface-deform

Is it possible to use "Preverse volume" from the Armature modifier but only for some body parts? Because it's really usefull for some parts of the mesh but not for most of the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 new vertex groups, one containing only vertices you want to preserve volume, the other all others vertices.

Add a new armature modifier targeting your rig, and use the vertex group limit function to have the desired result.

[image]

Another method using one new vertex group only:

[image]